# Ford Focus 2008 Error code: P2585-61

Tags: ford, obd-ii, focus

I own a Ford Focus 2008 1.6 TDCI. Recently I filled the DPF Additive tank with EOLYS Fluid but I couldn't regenerate and reset the values that day, so I drove to my home.

Following day, I went to work at my lunch time. I took my car to the repairman to regenerate and reset the values.

The problem started showing up after it had been completed successfully, the IDS was showing an error:

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

[image: Error Code]

EDIT:

P.S. forgot to tell that a year ago I had ran out of fluid, I couldn't find any solution and fluid for around 3 or 4 months. When I found the fluid I bought only 1 liter(they said it's enough). For the next 2 months everything was ok, then it started showing me P2584 error code until now that I have filled it full

Comment: Interesting.  Have learned more about the issue that you can add to your question?